# How to create objects when the count is not known in prior

Tags: c++

How to create objects if I dont know in prior how many to create.?For example I am creating an application and I dont know in prior how many users are going to use? So should I declare fixed number of objects(Say Myclass obj[200]) or can I dynamically create as and when I want or have a new user?

Comment: Use a `std::vector<Myclass>` instead.

Comment: We've had `std::vector` and other collections for decades. [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: make a linked list by hand -- well, actually bad idea, just go with two previous comments and use some libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the NEW keyword to assignate the numberofusers (variable) needed

```
Myclass[] obj= new Myclass [NumberOfUsers];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a vector:

```
std::vector<Myclass> obj;
```

This way you can change its size quickly using:

```
vector::resize() and vector::reserve()
```